# Recipient View - ID Check Authentication disable

Tags: docusignapi

I have been facing this issue in production API, when the user receives the document to sign and when he opens the link it redirects to ID Check. 
Please refer the attached screenshot.

In my C# I haven't enabled any authentication method.

```
Signer signer = new Signer();
signer.Email = recipientEmail;
signer.Name = recipientName;
signer.RecipientId = "1";
signer.RoutingOrder = "1";

signer.Tabs = new Tabs();
signer.Tabs.SignHereTabs = new List<SignHere>();
SignHere signHere = new SignHere();
signHere.DocumentId = "1";
signHere.PageNumber = "1";
signHere.RecipientId = "1";
signHere.XPosition = "110";
signHere.YPosition = "665";
signer.Tabs.SignHereTabs.Add(signHere);

envDef.Recipients = new Recipients();
envDef.Recipients.Signers = new List<Signer>();
envDef.Recipients.Signers.Add(signer);

envDef.Status = "sent";

EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();

EnvelopeSummary envelopeSummary=envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(accountId, envDef);
```

This is all of my code. Please assist

ID Check screen

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have Authentication Settings turned on at an account level. These settings will apply to all the envelopes sent from the account by Default. You will have change it to a different option incase you do not want to enforce it by default for every envelope.

You can view your existing accountSettings using the [listSettings](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Accounts/Accounts/listSettings/) api. Look for the **idCheckRequired** setting. You can find the definition of these settings [here](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Accounts/Accounts/create/#account-settings)

---

**Changing your account Settings**

See the following admin guides to change your Account settings through the Docusign admin console.

- **New Docusign Sending Experience** (Documentation [here](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-admin-guide-security-settings))

[image]

- **Classic Docusign Sending Experience** (Documentation [here](https://www.docusign.com/supportdocs/cdse-admin-guide/Content/account-admin/authentication-options.htm))

[image]

- Note: You should have account Admin privileges to modify the Account settings.

Comment: Yes that was the issue. Authentication settings were turned on from account level. Contacted docusign customer support and sorted this out. Since I have purchased the basic API plan, Authentication settings were not visible to me at the account level and only docusign support could disable it. Thank you very much!

Comment: I have the intermediate plan and I've disabled this but it's still showing up for me every time. Not sure why I can't disable it.

Comment: I have the same issue; disabled it entirely on the account (Starter), but still get ID verification screen when you try to sign. Opening a support ticket with DocuSign.

Comment: Have you solved this problem? I have faced with this problem as well.