# How to disable DocuSign ID Check during signing

Tags: docusignapi

We are using basic api plan for production. Just received our production key. when a doc loads for signing, we see the ID check page.

Can it be skipped? We want to see our doc without this step

[image]

Comment: Did my answer resolve your question?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your Api plan, you can change the default Id Check authentication option in your account settings.
See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42362045/recipient-view-id-check-authentication-disable/42371886)

Since you have a basic Api plan, you will have to contact DocuSign customer support to disable the default id Check authentication.

Comment: Admin Panel > Security Settings > Recipient Authentication Settings - Make sure _The sender can require that a recipient must authenticate on any envelope sent from this account_ is selected.

Comment: I have the same issue; disabled it entirely on the account, but still get ID verification screen when you try to sign.